# Задание № 22 ЕГЭ – поиск контекстных синонимов

Tags: лексика, синонимы, анализ-текста

> (17)Каждую весну, в апреле или мае, волчица приносила детёнышей. (18)Но только один раз за всю жизнь ей удалось выкормить своих волчат, — она была счастлива в то лето... (19)Потом её детей, подросших и крепких, продали в цирк. (20)Она-то, конечно, этого не знала, но как больно, как тоскливо ей было тогда! (21)Будоража весь зоопарк, она выла днями и ночами, и ей подвывал волк. (22)Но ещё страшнее было тогда, когда её детёныши пропадали в тот же день, в который они появлялись на свет.

Какие два слова из этого отрывка являются контекстными синонимами?

(Свой вариант ответа у меня есть, но сбивать с мысли отвечающих не хочется.)

Comment: Два слова? Я вижу три. В этом и подвох?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова вот я-то тут тоже три вижу — но ведь школьники, безусловно, без труда расправятся с лексикологической проблемой, о которой даже специалисты не имеют единого мнения... вот мы три видим, а уже известный нам автор (завтра скину имя) обнаружил два слова, которые ну уж совсем с натяжкой синонимичны.

Comment: Может быть, имелось в виду _Какие два слова из этого отрывка являются контекстными синонимами?_  — третьему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дети и детёныши, по-моему, обычные синонимы,  дети и волчата - да. Я вот здесь ещё парочку контекстных рассмотрела: больно, тоскливо. Вообще-то это не синонимы, а здесь синонимы.

Answer (score 2):

Контекстные синонимы: **дети и детёныши**.

**Волчата и детеныши** ― это разные обозначения молодых животных в данном тексте, но они не являются синонимами, так как у них разное значение: волчата ― это не просто детеныши, а детеныши волка.

**Дети и детёныши** ―  синонимы в данном тексте, то есть контекстные синонимы, они имеют значение "молодые животные".

Comment: Мне нравится ваша мысль, но автор пособия дал другой ответ...

Comment: Тогда интрига сохраняется, подождите других ответов.

Comment: А разве волчата — это не _молодые животные?_

Comment: Здесь нет тождества.  Волчата - это молодые животные (детеныши) волка.

Answer (score 1):

Контекстные синонимы — это слова, которые близки по значению только в данном тексте (отрывке, главе из книги), так как они относятся к одному объекту, предмету.
Иногда их ещё называют ситуативными, окказиональными, авторскими, индивидуальными.

Контекстные синонимы играют уникальную роль в восполнении лексической недостаточности слова (в рамках авторского контекста) и позволяют выразить мысль наиболее точно и емко.

Я нашла здесь три контекстных синонима: детеныши, волчата, дети.

Comment: @Aer Ну тогда остается последний вариант — **дети** (маленькие "человеки") и **волчата** (маленькие волки).